safe-area-inset-bottom on iOS18
It seems the latest version of safari on the newly updated iOS (only a few weeks old as of this post) has a bug relating to safe-area-inset-bottom. A fixed bottom nav displays fine, and adjusts on scroll up/down as the address bar shrinks and expands, but if there is a use action that causes the address bar to auto-expand, it is overtop of the fixed content.
Has anyone else noticed this or discovered a solution? Its brand new, I tested on iOS17 and its fine.

any luck with this? we're stuck with the same problem

Yep, I've seen the same problem. I'm using dvh to set heights so it should account for the address bar but it sometimes does not (until the user interacts with an input). I'll let you know if I find a solution, I'm trying a few different things.

@1911z see my answer, I found a solution at least in my case.

We were seeing the same problem. I fixed it by triggering a scroll on the page, and on the elements that were underneath the browser controls, when the fixed element was made visible on the page. For us this was a cart popup that comes in from the right hand side of the screen. For some reason, triggering scrolls will reflow things and make it all work. I would experiment manually first scrolling different elements, once you find something that works, trigger the scroll programmatically e.g. (el.scroll({top: 100})).
I'm not sure if it's the scroll on the window or on the elements that fixes it, but this seems to be a workaround for now.
